# How to find out when Contact added to a Group

Tags: civimember, groups, smartgroups, date-range

I'm trying to find out when people were added to a SmartGroup. I want to be able to see when they joined the group so I can see when their membership is expiring.

Anyway to do this? I have tried doing searches via Manage Groups as well as in Reports, but I can't seem to find any dropdown/filter for 'Date Added to Group' e.g.

Any help would be appreciated!

J

Comment: you refer to 'member' but if you are using civimemver then you would already be able to see when their 'membership' is expiring - but perhaps you are using 'membership' in a different context? (but you do have a 'civimember' tag on this Q.

Answer (score 4):

If its a smart group I don't think you'll be able to do what you want as its actually a saved search and each time you look at membership its recalculated so there is no concept of when the contact joins the group.

If it were a normal group, there is a plugin https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory that produces a report gives details of when an individual joins and leaves the group. Its not working for me at the moment (CiviCRM 5.35.1 on WordPress) though it did when I originally tried it, showing a full history of be added to and removed from a group. Maybe the author https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/12/jon-g-megaphone-tech can help?

Comment: I'd like to help - but as you point out, you can't know when someone joined a smart group.  Joshua - it sounds like maybe your data structure has a flaw in it.  If you say what the criteria are for someone joining a smart group, it may be possible for someone to tell you how to find what you're looking for.  You may also want to consider using CiviRules + a non-smart group (and/or CiviMember) to actually issue a membership/join a "normal" group when criteria are met, which would give you what you're looking for - but only moving forward.